# How to create account on sonatype so I can publish Maven archive?

Tags: java, maven

I've been running an open source project for several years now and have had periodic requests to publish it to Maven.  Unfortunately, I have found the Maven publishing process to be extremely confusing and have yet to complete it successfully.  I believe the last time someone did it on my behalf and it resulted in http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.kitfox.svg/svg-salamander/1.0

Anyhow the the project is now at version 1.0.39 while the Maven repository one is 1.0.8.  I'd like to update it, and I have what I believe is a valid pom.xml file.  However, when I run 'mvn deploy', I receive the error

```
Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
```

After doing some searching, it seemed like I needed to create an account on sonatype.org so that I have a place to upload the file to.  However, Sonatype does not have any obvious feature on their website to let you create an account.  I'm not sure if they used to but then depreciated it or if there is some other process entirely that I'm supposed to go through.

Comment: You should read this: http://central.sonatype.org/

Comment: or this, to be exact: http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html

Comment: It is strange that during your several years you never encountered the instructions that are linked right there in the front page

Comment: however, if someone has done it on your behalf and you want to update that exact one with same maven coordinates, it is probably more complicated.